# Razor @helper functions not rendering any Html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model with an `object` property, and a value type id number, and want to create a different editor control depending on the value type number.

I'm trying to use `@help` razor contructs, however none of the contents of the helpers are rendered to the page.

```
@helper noEditor()
{
    <div>noEditor</div>
}
@helper stringEditor()
{
    <div>stringEditor</div>
}
@helper intEditor()
{
    <div>intEditor</div>
}
@helper boolEditor()
{
    <div>boolEditor</div>
}
@helper collectionEditor()
{
    <div>collectionEditor</div>
}

@switch(Model.ValueTypeId)
{
    case 1: stringEditor(); break;
    case 2: intEditor(); break;
    case 3: boolEditor(); break;
    case 4: collectionEditor(); break;
    default: noEditor(); break;
}
```

When I put a break point on the `@switch` I can see the debugger move to the correct helper, but it skips immediately to the end of the function then exits the switch, nothing is rendered.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To render text with Razor you have to use the @ sign. If you change your code to

```
@switch(Model.ValueTypeId)
{
    case 1: @stringEditor() break;
    case 2: @intEditor() break;
    case 3: @boolEditor() break;
    case 4: @collectionEditor() break;
    default: @noEditor() break;
}
```

it should work.

Alternative you can use `Response.Write` like this:

```
@switch(Model.ValueTypeId)
{
    case 1: Response.Write(stringEditor()); break;
    case 2: Response.Write(intEditor()); break;
    case 3: Response.Write(boolEditor()); break;
    case 4: Response.Write(collectionEditor()); break;
    default: Response.Write(noEditor()); break;
}
```

which is basically what the `@` does in razor.

Comment: It's always something simple like this that makes me tear my hair out. I'll make correct soon as the timer is up. Thank you sir.

Comment: Yeah, it usually is :) No problems, glad I could help.

Comment: You have to use "@" even if you are using the helper immediately after a "@if".  For example: `@if(Model.Any()) { @Html.EditorFor(...); }`